# Show particular data in dropdown

Tags: laravel, voyager

How to exclude database row from the select menu ? For example: The admin can create user and append roles to them. The available roles are dev, admin, normal user. But the admin user have to see only the admin and normal user roles. I know I can add them in the BREAD menu but I want to restrict the vision on dev role and when another roles are added to show them automaticaly and not to add them on by one in the BREAD menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to filter the set of roles pulled from the database. Since I am not familiar with your database schema, here is a rough solution that you should be able to tweak to your needs

```
$rolesQuery = Role::newQuery();

if (Auth::user()->is_admin) {
    $rolesQuery->where('role', '!=', 'dev');
}

$roles = $rolesQuery->get();
```

You can cache this result for admins for future use.

Comment: Thank you! Thats enough.